# Building apps with Fastlane and Phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, fastlane

What is the easiest way to integrate Fastlane with phonegap app builds? For the past two years we have been using just phonegap to build our apps by hand which can be a tedious process. Now that we are growing and need to start being able to re-release apps we are looking for a fast/easy solution that can streamline this whole process. I've searched around on the webs and fastlane repository and I don't see much about integration with phonegap. Any information or resources would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We have been using fastlane since its inception (migrated from shezhen etc) with Cordova (not quite the same as Phonegap, but close enough) and have found it to be extremely time saving. The main difference I believe is using the phonegap build service, which you can theoretically invoke though fastlane, using a shell command, although I recommend building locally.

I also recommend installing Fastlane with their brew package. (assuming you are on a Mac)

`brew cask install fastlane`

Run in the root of your project:

`fastlane init`

This will set up a master fastlane directory, where you will manage both Android and iOS from.

Our directory structure looks like this:

`── fastlane
│   ├── Appfile
│   ├── Deliverfile
│   ├── Fastfile
│   ├── Gymfile
│   ├── Matchfile
│   ├── Supplyfile
│   └── metadata`

and our fastfile looks something like this:

```
fastlane_version "2.1.1"

default_platform :ios

app_name = "REDACTED"
app_identifier = CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig.try_fetch_value(:app_identifier)

platform :ios do

  lane :development_profiles do
    match(type: 'development', app_identifier: "#{app_identifier}")
    match(type: 'development', app_identifier: "#{app_identifier}.MessagesExtension")
  end

  lane :appstore_profiles do
    match(type: 'appstore', app_identifier: "#{app_identifier}")
    match(type: 'appstore', app_identifier: "#{app_identifier}.MessagesExtension")
  end

  lane :profiles do
    development_profiles
    appstore_profiles
  end

  lane :build_development do
    development_profiles
    gym(
      configuration: "Debug",
      output_name: "#{app_name}-development.ipa"
    )
  end

  lane :build_release do
    appstore_profiles
    gym(
      configuration: "Release",
      output_name: "#{app_name}-release.ipa"
    )
  end

  lane :hockeyapp do |options|
    hockey(
      ipa: "REDACTED",
      dsym: "REDACTED",
      api_token: "REDACTED",
      notes: "Build " + (ENV["BUILD_NUMBER"] ? ENV["BUILD_NUMBER"] + " " : "") + "From " + git_branch + " branch on " + Time.now.strftime('%F') + " at " + Time.now.strftime('%T'),
      notify: "0"
    )
  end

  lane :ci do
    build_development
    hockeyapp
  end

  lane :beta do
    build_release
    pilot
  end

  lane :release do
    deliver(
      ipa: "REDACTED",
      force: true,
      skip_metadata: true,
      skip_screenshots: true
    )
  end

  lane :screenshots do
    deliver(
      skip_binary_upload: true
    )
  end

  after_all do |lane|
  end

  error do |lane, exception|
  end
end

platform :android do

  lane :build_development do
    Dir.chdir ".." do
      sh("platforms/android/cordova/clean")
    end
    gradle(
      task: "cdvBuildDebug",
      project_dir: "platforms/android/",
      properties: {
        'android.useDeprecatedNdk' => true
      }
    )
    Dir.chdir ".." do
      sh("mkdir -p REDACTED/")
      sh("cp -f platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-armv7-debug.apk REDACTED/")
      sh("cp -f platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-x86-debug.apk REDACTED/")
    end
  end

  lane :build_release do
    Dir.chdir ".." do
      sh("platforms/android/cordova/clean")
    end
    gradle(
      task: "cdvBuildRelease",
      project_dir: "platforms/android/",
      properties: {
        'android.useDeprecatedNdk' => true
      }
    )
    Dir.chdir ".." do
      sh("mkdir -p REDACTED/")
      sh("cp -f platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-armv7-release.apk REDACTED/")
      sh("cp -f platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-x86-release.apk REDACTED/")
    end
  end

  lane :hockeyapp do |options|
    hockey(
      apk: "REDACTED",
      notes: "Build " + (ENV["BUILD_NUMBER"] ? ENV["BUILD_NUMBER"] + " " : "") + "From " + git_branch + " branch on " + Time.now.strftime('%F') + " at " + Time.now.strftime('%T'),
      notify: "0"
    )
  end

  lane :release do |options|
    supply(
      track: options[:track],
      apk_paths: ["REDACTED", "REDACTED"],
      skip_upload_metadata: true,
      skip_upload_images: true,
      skip_upload_screenshots: true
    )
  end

  lane :ci do
    build_development
    hockeyapp
  end

  after_all do |lane|
  end

  error do |lane, exception|
  end
end
```

The crux of it is, you treat your project as if it was a normal native project, and build it that way. Works quite well.

Comment: When running fastlane init in the root cordova directory I get an error saying something about how an xcode project was found in a subdirectory and to run fastlane init in the subdirectory. I assume that error can be ignored? The fastlane directory was indeed created even though this error was returned but the folder is empty.